# Getting Insufficient Privilege error in Jmeter for Oracle Application

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

While doing performance testing for Oracle Application, facing the Insufficient Privilege error on submitting one of the form from Jmeter. There is no issue manually in application not any error in debug logs. This is happening only from Jmeter. Have checked with Fiddler no requests are getting missed and also all the correlations are in place.

> **JMeter error :**
>   You have insufficient privileges for the current operation. Please contact your System Administrator.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're simply not getting logged in. Double check the following:

1. [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) is added to your Test Plan. In some cases you will need to add `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` line to *user.properties* file or amend `Cookie Policy` to something less-restrictive, i.e. `netscape`. Check out [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)
2. Make sure that you perform **correlation** of dynamic request parameters. Pay attention to literally everything as parameters may be present as a part of the [URL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier), or it may be a [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
3. Run your test with 1 user and monitor the request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Check `Response Data` tab for each request to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing
4. Make sure to compare the requests originating from JMeter and from the real browser, normally if you're sending the same requests - you should be receiving the same responses. Pay attention to [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)